# Jquery toggle tablerow on/off

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table where every second table row has a class name of "hideme". In my css file I have made

```
.hideme { display:none}
```

The hidden row contains a password field and a button. Only a single hidden row can be shown at any given time. As it is now the jquery code that makes the toggle function works pretty well. However it won't let me click inside the hidden row, without closing it, making it impossible to type anything in the text field.

How should I change my jquery code to allow clicking inside the hidden rows without anything happening?

My jquery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#eventtable tr').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none') {
            $('#eventtable .hideme').hide();
            $(this).next().toggle();
        }
        else {
            $('#eventtable .hideme').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

you can see a fiddle of how the code is currently working here: http://jsfiddle.net/aTN6v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#eventtable tr:not(.hideme)').on('click', function() {
...
});
```

Comment: This is the only solution I have tried that works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function inside an if block to check if the row is or not a .hideme

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#eventtable tr').on('click', function() {

    if(!$(this).hasClass('.hideme')) {

        if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none') {
            $('#eventtable .hideme').hide();
            $(this).next().toggle();
        }
        else {
            $('#eventtable .hideme').hide();
        }

    }
    });
});
```